# SQL как получить все значения определенного столбца в таблице

Tags: sql

У меня есть вот такая таблица:
[image: Обзор таблицы]

Подскажите каким SQL запросом, я могу получить все значения столбца `value` игнорируя другие столбцы. То есть в данном случае результат: [0.05, 0.051]

Comment: `select value from t`, если без повторов то `distinct value`

Comment: @teran Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select value from t
```

В инструкцию select нужно передать только название столбца value